# Für welche transitiven Verben kann "Qualia" Objekt sein? "Haben", "Empfinden"...?

Tags: word-choice

*Qualia*, der "subjektive Erlebnisgehalt mentaler Zustände" (s. z.B. [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/wiki/Qualia)), sind seit über 100 Jahren Objekte (oder müsste man sagen "Subjekte"?) philosophischer Diskussionen (Qualiaproblem).

Der Begriff ist spannend, aber was ich eigentlich gerne wüsste ist, wie man ihn im Zusammenhang mit einem Verb verwendet.

"Habe" ich Qualia? "Empfinde" ich Qualia"? "Erlebe" ich sie? Oder kennt jemand eine noch passendere Wendung?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing which came into my mind was `Perception of Qualia`. Yields alot [results](http://www.google.com/search?num=30&hl=en&q=%22perception%20of%20qualia%22&).  In English [*perceive Qualia*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22perceive%20qualia%22&ie=UTF-8) seems the most common. So *empfinden/wahrnehmen* in German seems correct to me.

Comment: I found more "Qualia wahrnehmen" than "empfinden". So I guess that's top of the list. That's seems also to be the best translation for "perceive". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Diese Frage ist wahrscheinlich besser in Philosophie aufgehoben. Grammatikalisch kannst Du jedes Verb damit verwenden. Ob das jeweilige Wort Sinn ergibt, können dir eher die Philosophen wohl genauer sagen.

Comment: Das hatte ich sogar überlegt, mich dann aber, weil es nicht um Qualia als solche ging, sondern eher um die sprachliche Verwendung, für German Language entschieden. Vielleicht ein Grenzfall. Danke jedenfalls für die Antwort!

Comment: @Hackworth: Die Frage ist aber eben, welche Verben _semantisch_ erlaubt sind. Für die Beantwortung mögen Philosophen besonders qualifiziert sein. Aber die Frage ist doch analog dazu, welche Verben z.B. mit "Euphorie" verwendet werden können - und da sind semantisch wohl nur wenige möglich.